# JavaScript search array of objects on condition

Tags: javascript

I have a following array of quiz objects as follows, and each quiz object has a `popupTime` key:

```
var quizzes = {
    "quizzes": [
        {
            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e1859",
            "popupTime": 2.24,
            "lectureId": 5008,
            "__v": 0,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "title": "Which is the capital of India",
                    "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e185f",
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "answer": "Delhi",
                            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e1863",
                            "correct": true
                        },
                        {
                            "answer": "Bangalore",
                            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e1862",
                            "correct": false
                        },
                        {
                            "answer": "Mumbai",
                            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e1861",
                            "correct": false
                        },
                        {
                            "answer": "Chennai",
                            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e1860",
                            "correct": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Where is housing located? ",
                    "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e185a",
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "answer": "Delhi",
                            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e185e",
                            "correct": false
                        },
                        {
                            "answer": "Bangalore",
                            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e185d",
                            "correct": true
                        },
                        {
                            "answer": "Mumbai",
                            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e185c",
                            "correct": false
                        },
                        {
                            "answer": "Chennai",
                            "_id": "546060033ea982a04f2e185b",
                            "correct": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
      {
    "_id" : "5460640d1e8743ee61413690",
    "popupTime" : 169,
    "lectureId" : 5008,
    "questions" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Is this the 2nd quiz in same lecture?",
            "_id" : "5460640d1e8743ee61413691",
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "answer" : "True",
                    "_id" : "5460640d1e8743ee61413693",
                    "correct" : true
                }, 
                {
                    "answer" : "False",
                    "_id" : "5460640d1e8743ee61413692",
                    "correct" : false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
    ]
};
```

Which is the most efficient way to scan the entire quiz object and get one object which satisfies the `popupTime = 169` and save it in another object?

Efficient in terms of execution time on repeated calls. I will be performing the same operation on the same array many times to check for the condition.

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: Define 'efficiency'. Execution time? Execution time on repeated calls? Less lines of code?

Comment: Execution time on repeated calls. I will be performing the same operation on the same array many times to check for the conditoion

Comment: You don't have worry about efficiency. Or rather, you need to first worry about efficiency of your time, both coding this initially and maintaining it. The first step is to write **something** which works. Then you can worry about making it efficient, it in fact it really turns out to be a bottleneck in your code, which is **highly** unlikely.

Comment: @torazaburo your right but I want to consider all the options and the best way other developers would do it. Just exploring the best way

Comment: Best !== most efficient. Any > none.

Comment: but Best == most efficient

Comment: @Ajey You need to understand that that statement is incorrect.

Comment: Downvotes are likely coming from the fact that you have apparently made no effort whatsoever to solve this yourself. SO is for answering questions about programming, it's not a free coding service.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a coding problem which the OP has made no effort to solve himself.

Comment: Yes true, I will take care of that henceforth. Thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64626/discussion-between-ajey-and-torazaburo).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, you use a seperate `array` that's purpose is to `index your object` by popupTime. Therefor create a seperate `array`:

```
var indexArray = [];
```

Every time you insert a new `Object` into your `quizzes`, also insert the `popupTime` into this array:

```
indexArray.push(yournewObject.popupTime);
```

Then you can find your Element by using the `Array.prototype.indexOf` method:

```
var yourSearchedObject = quizzes[indexArray.indexOf(169)];
```

Comment: this may not be possible because I am pulling up this quizzes from mongoDb service. And it gives me on big fat array of objects

Comment: Well you could iterate over this big fat array once and set up your index array

Answer (score 1):

You can index your collection by `popupTime` to perform `O(1)` lookups. Assuming `popupTime` is unique.

```
function index(collection, by) {
   var cache = {}, i = 0, len = collection.length, item;
   for(; i < len; ++i) { //for is faster than forEach and it's friends
      item = collection[i];
      cache[item.key] = item;
   }

   return function findOne(key) {
       return cache[key];
   }
}

var findByPopupTime = index(quizzes.quizzes, 'popupTime');
var quiz169 = findByPopupTime(169);
```